# using 2 observableCollections with same referenced objects loses values of dependencyProperties - wpf

Tags: wpf, vb.net, observablecollection

i have 2 instances of observableCollection

```
Public Property Reports As New ObservableCollection(Of Report)
Public Property AvailableReports As New ObservableCollection(Of Report)
```

the first list is filled upon initialization, and the second gets filled with objects from the first list that respect certain conditions.

```
For Each rep As Report In Reports
    If rep.Width = _customWidth
        AvailableReports.Add(rep)
    End If
Next
```

when doing so, a dependencyProperty 'IsSelected' in the Report loses its value; so that if one object 'x' in Reports list has 'IsSelected = True', after adding it to the AvailableReports list 'x.IsSelected ' would return False.

Here is the code for the Report class

```
Public Class Report
Inherits DependencyObject
Implements IComparable(Of Report)

Public Property Layout As Byte()
Public Property reportId As Integer
Public Property Name As String
Public Property Width As Double

Public Shared ReadOnly IsSelectedProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsSelected", GetType(Boolean), GetType(Report))
Public Property IsSelected As Boolean
    Get
        Return GetValue(IsSelectedProperty)
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        SetValue(IsSelectedProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Public Function CompareTo(other As Report) As Integer Implements IComparable(Of Report).CompareTo
    Return Me.Width.CompareTo(other.Width)
End Function
```

End Class

Comment: Probably your binding on the IsSelected becomes a localvalue.

Comment: Maybe becouse you are assingning and not checking If rep.Width = _customWidth

Comment: Can you show the class ReportTemplteLayout. Should it not to be so: AvailableReports.Add(rep)?

Comment: @Rekshino yes ur right, i just wrote it wrong, and also sorry the compare should be to the report class, i edited the question.

Comment: i did a workaround by cloning the instance rep of a Report `AvailableReports.Add(new Report(rep))` and that solved it. but i didn't understand why the problem was happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your issue. If I create an object and put them to different ObservableCollections, then this object has a same values, also by dependency properties and it can not be else, because the collections share the same object, which is of reference type. If I bind these collections to different ui controls and bind IsSelected property, then changing the property in one control causes changing the selection in another.
Revise your code, whether the code you have posted matches to you real code. It should work.

Comment: Most probably i had a problem with the ui and it was causing this behavior, thnx